# IKAnalyzer loadExtendWords

Tags: java

I got a question when I use the IKAnalyzer as a Chinese Segmentation

and I just want to load my own extend words to dictionary, but it does not seem to work:

code follows:

```
        Dictionary dic = Dictionary.getInstance();
        Dictionary.loadExtendWords(Arrays.asList("abc"));
        Dictionary.loadExtendWords(Arrays.asList("abc2013"));
        Dictionary.loadExtendWords(Arrays.asList("学校2013"));
        String testString = "test abc abc2013 Chineses:学校2013";
        Analyzer analyzer = new IKAnalyzer(true);
        TokenStream ts = analyzer.tokenStream("demo", new StringReader(testString));
        ts.reset();
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String t = null;
        while (ts.incrementToken()) {
            t = ts.getAttribute(CharTermAttribute.class).toString();

            sb.append(t).append(" ");
            System.out.print(t + "|");

        }
        ts.end();
        ts.close();
```

the output is "test|abc|abc2013|chineses|学校|2013|", as you can see the self-defined word "学校2013" does not work.

it seems that IKAnalyzer is not useful for mix of Chineses and English.

Comment: What's your actual question?

Comment: As I said,the main problem is when i add a word(eg.  学校2013 ,a combination of Chinese and number) into IKAnalyze's dictionary,the analyzer seem not to split the right words. It should be "学校2013" because I added it into the dictionay,but the split result is "学校" "2013".